# How do I fix this TEXT function in a VLOOKUP which returns a value from a sheet in a workbook that is located in the same folder?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, syntax, vlookup

The following formula presents an error that suggests that I enclose the VLOOKUP in quotes, as I may not have meant to express a formula. But I do want that. The parentheses surrounding the parameters of the TEXT function are highlighted in red for some reason, though I'm unsure why.

`=VLOOKUP(A40,'[sales_&TEXT(TODAY()-7,"mm.dd.yyyy")&]Fruit_Sales'!A:B,2,FALSE)` 
I am working with Excel 2019, which is compatible with the TEXT function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I removed the TEXT function out of the VLOOKUP formula and replaced it with the path to a file named with today's date. The VLOOKUP works as expected when I do this and retrieves the data. I would just like for the function to be dynamic so that it will always retrieve the data from the Fruit_Sales sheet from 7 days ago.

Comment: Use [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Answer (score 0):

### INDIRECT (A Volatile Function)

**The INDIRECT formula**

- The formula will work once the source file is open. It will still show the correct result even after you close the source file.
- Once the file is closed, on the next recalculation (volatile!) of the sheet, it will show the `#REF!` error until you open the source file again.
- Next time you open the file, it will show a `#REF!` error until you open the source file again.

```
=VLOOKUP(A40,INDIRECT(D40),2,FALSE)
```

- Replace `D40` with either `Formula in D40`.

Formula in `D40`:

```
="'[sales_"&TEXT(TODAY()-7,"mm.dd.yyyy")&".xlsx]Fruit_Sales'!A:B"
```

Result in `D40`:

```
'[sales_03.06.2023.xlsx]Fruit_Sales'!A:B
```

**Adding the Path**

- Unfortunately, it'll make no difference in the behavior.

Path formula:

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1)
```

Formula in `D40`:

```
="'"&LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1)
    &"[sales_"&TEXT(TODAY()-7,"mm.dd.yyyy")&".xlsx]Fruit_Sales'!A:B"
```

Result in `D40`:

```
'C:\SomePath\[sales_03.06.2023.xlsx]Fruit_Sales'!A:B
```

**Conclusion**

- In a nutshell, it can't be done without you always opening the source file.

**A VBA Solution**

- It can be done using VBA.
- You will have to save the file as a `.xlsm` or `.xlsb` file and copy the following code to its `ThisWorkbook` module.
- Each time the workbook is opened, it will rewrite the formula in the whole column with the relevant (hard-coded) workbook name.

```vb
' This code needs to be copied to the 'ThisWorkbook' module
' of the correct file. Locate it in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R),
' double-click on it ('ThisWorkbook') and copy the code
' to the window that just opened. Save the file with the '.xlsm' extension.
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    ' Carefully adjust the values in the constants section, e.g.
    ' the column of the formula was never discussed.
    
    ' Destination
    Const DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "B" ' location of the formula
    
    ' Source
    Const SRC_DAYS_EARLIER As Long = 7
    Const SRC_NAME_LEFT As String = "sales_"
    Const SRC_DATE_FORMAT As String = "mm.dd.yyyy"
    Const SRC_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsx"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Fruit_Sales"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "A:B"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As Variant = 2
        
    ' '*** Identify the code name of the worksheet that contains the formula.
    ' It is the name not in parentheses in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R).
    ' Replace 'Sheet1' with it.
    
    ' The Range
    Dim rg As Range
    With Sheet1 ' ***
        Dim flCell As Range: Set flCell = .Range(DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL)
        Dim frCell As Range: Set frCell = .Cells(flCell.Row, DST_RETURN_COLUMN)
        Dim LastRow As Long:
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, flCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rg = .Range(frCell, .Cells(LastRow, frCell.Column))
    End With
    
    ' The Formula
    Dim Formula As String
    Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & DST_FIRST_LOOKUP_CELL & ",'" & Me.Path _
        & Application.PathSeparator & "[" & SRC_NAME_LEFT _
        & Evaluate("TEXT(TODAY()-" & SRC_DAYS_EARLIER & ",""" _
        & SRC_DATE_FORMAT & """)") & SRC_FILE_EXTENSION & "]" _
        & SRC_WORKSHEET_NAME & "'!" & SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS & "," _
        & SRC_RETURN_COLUMN & "," & "FALSE),"""")"
    
    ' Write!
    rg.Formula = Formula

End Sub
```

- If you don't want the IFERROR part, just remove `IFERROR(` and `,"""")` from the formula.